# Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-|f(x)|}dx$, where $f(x) = x-\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: integration, limits

> Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-|f(x)|}dx$, where $f(x) = x-\frac{1}{x}$

I am totally stuck on this one. One idea I had was to make the variable substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$: $$\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-|f(x)|}dx = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-|x-\frac{1}{x}|}dx \overset{\overset{\large t=\frac{1}{x} \iff x = \frac{1}{t}}{\large dx=\frac{-1}{x^2}}}{=========}-\int_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{-|\frac{1}{t} - t|}dt = \\[3ex] =\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{n}e^{-|\frac{1}{t} - t|}dt$$
but this, obviously, leads to $I=I$. Not very useful. I also thought of splitting the integral based on the roots of $f(x)$ (i.e. in $x=1$), however, those two integrals are just as hard as the original one. Any help to solve this is much appreciated!

Comment: First break it into two integrals, 1/n to 1, and 1 to n, to remove the absolute value.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I have done that, yet I was still unable to solve it. I really do not know what to do with an exponent such as $x-\frac{1}{x}$, if a substitution would somehow work or integration by parts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$\int\limits_{1/n}^1e^{x-x^{-1}}\,dx=
\int\limits_1^n x^{-2}e^{x^{-1}-x}\,dx$$
Therefore
$$\int\limits_{1/n}^ne^{-|x^{-1}-x|}\,dx=
\int\limits_{1}^ne^{x^{-1}-x}(1+x^{-2})\,dx=-e^{x^{-1}-x}\Big |_1^n\\ =1-e^{n^{-1}-n}\to 1$$